# Unable to generate excel from firebase in android studio

Tags: java, firebase

I wanted to get values from the Firebase database and then let the users get the results in an excel file, is it possible to include a library to help use the excel? If yes ,How can implement and what code to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) library with `firebase functions` to read the excel and store the data in firebase. But it has workbook write feature also. You can try this.